# Retrieving all twitter followers with a single request

Tags: php, twitter

I tried this and even added a cursor but it would still retrieve only the first 100 followers.

```
<?php
$cursor = -1;
$account_from = 'username';
do
  {
     $json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers/' .   $account_from .'.json?cursor=' . $cursor);

$accounts = json_decode($json);

foreach ($accounts->users as $account)
{

        $a[] = $account->screen_name ; 


}
$cursor = $accounts->next_cursor;


}
 while ($cursor > 0);

 foreach($a as $f) {

         echo $f ; 

   }


?>
```

Is there a better and simpler way of doing it? Where am i going wrong? help please?

Answer (score 0):

API docs state this request is deprecated:

> This method is deprecated as it will only return information about users who have Tweeted recently. It is not a functional way to retrieve all of a users followers. Instead of using this method use a combination of GET followers/ids and GET users/lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Use this API instead: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

There should be a property in your object called `next_cursor`, as long as that's non-zero, keep doing the request again (specifying that cursor) until you get all the results.